# Why does electron configuration in the periodic table is different when you follow the aufbau principle?

Tags: electronic-configuration

. In periodic table for example Ag has an electron configuration of [Kr] 4d10,5s1 but when you do it yourself using Aufbau principle it should be [Kr] 5s2 4d9. Why is that?

When ask for Ag + valence electron configuration answers may now vary because of the existence of two electron configurations from the periodic table and using aufbau principle...

Comment: Because the Aufbau principle is not taken as gospel by the electrons busy trying to solve Schrodinger's equation. It is not a law of nature, it is more of a general guideline for chemistry students that has problems, certainly with d electrons.

Comment: How come Sir that it serves as a general guideline if it doesn't match in what we see in the periodic table? Thank you.

Comment: I would not expect a general guideline to precisely match every single element in the periodic table. You have already noted that it doesn't, and basically I am saying that you should not expect it to. It is not a physical law. Adding d electrons makes for some funny things, and you have noted one of them. There are others.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, full electron shells are more stable than unfilled shells. In silver, promoting an electron from the 5s to the 4d shell completes the d orbital, which increases the stability of the 4d shell more than it destabilizes the 5s shell.
This is also explained here:

https://lavelle.chem.ucla.edu/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=2807